# Instantiation of classes in anonymous block

Tags: apex

I am running below code in anonymous block and i get some weird 'internal error'
cannot figure out why .

```
public class abcd
{public void m1()
{
system.debug('hi');
}

}
abcd objec = new abcd();
objec.m1();
```

Comment: It's probably related to the Summer 13 release. You can raise a case with support, but they probably already have this documented. I just confirmed that I too am getting an error trying to instantiate classes in an anonymous block. Defining the class works, however.

Comment: Works fine for me, in my Summer 13 org on NA10 ...

Comment: Works for me on CS3. What instance are you on?

Comment: I am on NA15,Summer

Comment: It worked for me without any issues on NA15.  I copied and pasted your code into the Developer Console and executed it.  Maybe it was some temporary problem that has been resolved.